# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration

> Find $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x^2+b^2)^2}dx$$

We see that the only poles are at $x=\pm bi$.  Integrating over the semicircular contour implies that it is equal to $2\pi i*Res_{(+bi)}$ because the integral over the circular arc is $0$.  So now I just need to calculate the residue at $+bi$. Can anyone give hints on how to do this?  I was thinking about multiplying by $(x-bi)^2$ and then evaluating at $bi$ but I'm not sure why this even makes sense.

Comment: How do you usually find residues?

Comment: We can find the $a_{-1}$ term of the laurent expansion.  Would this be too messy in this case though?  I'm also not sure how to find the laurent expansion in this case.

Comment: $x=b\tan \theta \implies dx=b\sec^2 \theta d\theta \implies \therefore\displaystyle\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+b^2)^2}=\dfrac{1}{b^4}\displaystyle \int\cos^2 \theta d\theta$

Comment: @BobbyJones If $z_0$ is a pole of order $k$ of $\varphi$, then $$\text{Res}(\varphi, z_0)=\dfrac 1{(k-1)!}\lim \limits_{z\to z_0}\left[\dfrac{\mathrm d^{k-1}}{\mathrm dz^{k-1}}\left(z\mapsto (z-z_0)^k\varphi(z)\right)(z)\right].$$ See an explanation in the first part of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804551/finding-the-poles-and-residues-of-a-complex-function-frac-cosz-1ez-1/804627#804627) answer.

Comment: so it would just be $\lim_{z\to bi}\frac{d}{dz}(\frac{1}{(z+bi)^2})(z)=1/4b^2$.  Assuming I did the calculations correctly

Comment: @BobbyJones That's not the value I'm getting. Consider posting your calculations in the question.

Comment: I did something wrong before.  Now I have $\lim \frac{1}{z+bi}+ \frac{-2z}{(z+bi)^3} = 1/2bi + 1/4b^2$  However, that seems even more wrong...

Comment: Are you interested in seeing methods that rely on 'Real' based techniques?

Answer (score 1):

A possible contour is the semi circle in the upper half plane with a semi circle around the origin. Let $\int_{\Gamma}$ be large semi circle and $\int_{\gamma}$ be the small semi circle. Let $R$ be the radius of the $\Gamma$ and $\epsilon$ the radius of $\gamma$. Now as $R\to\infty$, $\int_{\Gamma}\to 0$ and similarly as $\epsilon\to 0$, $\int_{\gamma}\to 0$ by the estimation lemma. Take the orientation of the contour to be counter clockwise.
Therefore, we can write you integral as
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)dz\\
&= \int_{\Gamma}+\int_{\gamma} + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)dz\\
&= 2\pi i\sum_{\text{UHP}}\text{Res}\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(z)dz &=2\pi i\sum_{\text{UHP}}\text{Res}
\end{align}
As you have been told in the comments, the residue for a pole which isn't simple is 
$$
2\pi i\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{(k - 1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}(z - z_0)^kf(z)
$$
In your case, the pole of order two in the upper half plane is $z_0 = ib$. That is,
\begin{align}
2\pi i\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{(k - 1)!}\frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}}(z - z_0)^kf(z) &= 2\pi i\lim_{z\to ib}\frac{1}{1!}\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{(z + ib)^2}\\
&= 2\pi i\lim_{z\to ib}\frac{-2}{(z+ib)^3}
\end{align}

Comment: The $2\pi i$ factor isn't part of the residue.

Comment: @GitGud it is part of Cauchy integral formula. Since we have no poles on the real axis which we are only taking a semi circle around, we pick up $2\pi i$ instead of the $\pi i$. Certain books will define the residue enclosed in a contour in this manner and have a separate definition for poles on the real axis which are then defined as $\pi i$ sum residues.