# Best way to calculate residues

Tags: residue-calculus, complex-integration

Basically, what is the best method to calculate residues, specifically, something like this:
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\frac{1+z}{1-\cos(z)}.
\end{equation*}

For simple poles, I can just use L'Hopital by using the fact that the Larent series will only have one negative power term in it (the ^-1 term). But if there are more poles, like a double pole or an essential singularity, how do I calculate the residue then? Thank you

Comment: Related: [When we have more than a single pole, i.e a double pole, triple pole etc. is it best to just try and find the Laurent expansion about the pole?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804551/finding-the-poles-and-residues-of-a-complex-function-frac-cosz-1ez-1).

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the order of the pole: 2 in this case. Write the Laurent series of $f$:
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=-2}^\infty a_n z^n.$$
Now,
$$1 + z = f(z)(1 - \cos z) = (a_{-2}z^{-2} + a_{-1}z^{-1} + a_0 + \cdots)(\frac{z^2}2 + \cdots)$$
Write the first terms of the product and... can you continue?

Comment: But how do you know it is pole or order 2? Given that information, I know how to do it, but how do you initially say it is a pole of order 2? Thanks for the fast response! :)

Comment: You either know the classical limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2}=\frac12$ and then apply the definition of degree of a Pole: unique $n$ s.t $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}z^nf(z)\ne \{0,\infty \}$. Or you taylor expand the denominator in order to make an *educated* guess and then verify it by the above formula (where you can apply Bernouilli de l'Hôpital  if you have chosen $n$ correctly)